# Spreadsheetgear: Error converting to Datetime

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to parse a cell value in excel sheet and convert it to Datetime using following code.But I'm getting an error as :

> 'arguments.CurrentWorksheet.Workbook.NumberToDateTime(inpDate)' threw
>   an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>       base: {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: Invalid date-time serial number."}
>       ActualValue: null
>       Message: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: Invalid date-time serial number."

Code:

```
double inpDate = arguments.GetNumber(2);
startDate = arguments.CurrentWorksheet.Workbook.NumberToDateTime(inpDate);
```

where inpDate  in the sheet is 20170113.

Could you advise please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the value of inpDate before the conversion? I think it is null

Comment: Hi Mihai...I debugged earlier and value of inpDate is 20170113.0.Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that means Tim's response is probably correct. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inpDate` is not a valid "Excel date."  Dates/times are stored in SpreadsheetGear and Excel as a `double` representing a date/time *serial number*.  Whole numbers represent days, with the value 1 being January 1, 1900 and the fractional portion of the number represents the time (i.e., 0.5 is noon).  So, for instance, a value of 42793.0 represents February 27, 2017 (12:00 AM).  You can read more about Excel dates on the following informative page:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

IWorkbook.[NumberToDateTime](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook~NumberToDateTime.html)(...) expects this sort of serial date, but your input of '20170113' (which I assume is supposed to represent Jan 13, 2017) is getting interpreted as a date way in the future, like somewhere close to the year 57,160 (20,170,113 days from Jan 1, 1900), which is too far out to be a valid date in Excel/SpreadsheetGear.

For your particular case, it seems more appropriate to use DateTime.[ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)(...), such as:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("20170113", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.(I had thought of this approach earlier.)